# PHP MySQL recipe search based on what ingredients are provided

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, recipe

Say I have a database of recipes, and I want to search through them based on what ingredients I have.

There should be 3 tables:

Recipes (rid, rname),
Ingredients (iid, iname),
Relationship (rid, iid)

Next, lets imagine I have a recipe for 'toast' and a recipe for 'bread and butter pudding' - Toast has 2 ingredients (bread and butter) - The pudding might have bread and butter, plus flour, eggs and water - so thats 5 in total.

My problem is, structuring an SQL query based on what ingredients are provided in a search. If I submit 3 ingredients in my search - bread, butter and eggs - then (from the 2 recipes discussed) only one result should be produced - Toast! - because there aren't enough ingredients to make the pudding!

So what does such a sql query actually look like? I have tried everything, googled everything and now my brain cannot deal with it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best way, but for the example you gave it will work:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    recipes
WHERE
    rid NOT IN (
        /* exclude all recipes with other ingredients */
        SELECT rid FROM relationship WHERE iid NOT IN (1, 2, 4)
    )
```

Sorry for my english =)

Edit: the ingredients' ids are in the same order that they're in your question, so 1 is Bread, 2 is Butter, 4 is Eggs:

"iid";"iname"
"1";"Bread"
"2";"Butter"
"3";"Flour"
"4";"Eggs"
"5";"Water"

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the list of `iids` is given (1,2,3), you might try selecting all from `relationship` where the `iid` is in (1,2,3) and the `rid` is in (the selection of `rids` in `relationship` having a count<=number of `iids` in list)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose 'ids' holds searching ingredients ids.

```
SELECT *
FROM Recipes
WHREE rid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT rid FROM Relationship WHERE iid NOT IN (ids))
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer assumes you are using PDO but you modify to your needs if using basic mysql or mysqli calls:

```
$ingredient1 = $_POST['ingredient1'];
$ingredient2 = $_POST['ingredient2'];
$ingredient3 = $_POST['ingredient3'];

$sql = '
SELECT
 c.rid,
 c.rname
FROM ingredients a
JOIN relationship b ON (a.iid = b.iid)
JOIN recipes c ON (b.rid = c.rid)
WHERE
     (a.iname LIKE ? AND a.iname LIKE ? AND a.iname LIKE ?)
';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql)
$stmt->execute(array('%'.$ingredient1.'%', '%'.$ingredient2.'%', '%'.$ingredient3.'%'));
```

My answer assumes of course your statement will always include three recipes and you are using post variables but can be modified to accomodate variability as well. The benefits of this type of query as well contrasted to others given is that you don't have to use subqueries, which are traditionally less efficient.

### edit

forgot to add '%' symbols in the array values. This will match any ingredient name you have in the corresponding table. If it *must* match, simply remove 'LIKE' and '%' symbols and place '= ?'.